# how to extract a sample from a database

Tags: sql, r, database

I have a database with 15 Million of observations and I need to extract a sample in R to make some analytics, this is my code:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "Warehouse")

sample <- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT id, age, amount FROM score_monitor ORDER BY id")

first_100 <- dbFetch(sample, n = 100)
```

The problem is as the Database is too large it doesnt work like this. Is there any other idea to make this happen?...Thanks

Comment: What DBMS are you connecting to (SQL Server, MySQL, etc...)? You'll want to place your filter in the SQL "SELECT id, age, amount FROM score_monitor WHERE RowNum <= 100 ORDER BY id " (Oracle example). I don't know much about R, but this looks like it loads the whole table into "sample", then pares it down.

Comment: Your code seems fine. What error are you getting ?

Comment: Here is the link to the Microsoft docs on this topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc441928.aspx